# How can I change a network device's icon?

Tags: finder, network, icon

I know how to change icons in Finder by pasting them into the Get Info window.

But this doesn't work for Network devices.

For linux shares for example, this can be added to smb.service for avahi so MacOS will assign the Xserve icon to the share.

```
  <service>
    <type>_device-info._tcp</type>
    <port>0</port>
    <txt-record>model=Xserve</txt-record>
  </service>
```

How could this be done for another MacOS share on the network?
For example, make my Macbook's icon appear as an AppleTV?

[image: These are the devices icons I'd like to change]

They are not themselves drives, and as such have no filesystem to attach an icon to, it would have to be done via an smb setting to spoof the device as if it were another kind of Apple device as laid out in the linux example.

Comment: The icon has to be on the device. For example, I have a Synology NAS and done USB drives. By putting the icon at the root of the mount point, macOS automatically sets the icon for you.  I get an image of the Synology device and a WD logo for my external drive.

Comment: That may change the icon of a share *on* a network device, but I'd like to change the icon that is displayed for the device itself

Comment: Which device and where?

Comment: A share on a Network device can have an icon file in it's root because it has a filesystem (e.g Macintosh HD or 'Movies'). A Device in the network list is not a share and has no filesystem, it's the device on which the shares reside (e.g MacBook Pro)

Comment: "*How can this be done for another MacOS **share** on the network?*"  Are we talking about shares or network *devices*?  They are very different things.  Also, AppleTV has an OS residing atop a filesystem.  So, at the risk of sounding redundant... ***which devices and where?***